# Compass is defining path for sprites in "/image" instead of "/img"

Tags: sass, compass-sass, assetic

Here's my `config.yml` from Symfony2 :

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MnpirlMainBundle, MnpirlDashboardBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        compass: ~

parameters:
    assetic.filter.compass.images_dir:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web/img
    assetic.filter.compass.generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/img
    assetic.filter.compass.http_path: img/
```

The problem is that when dumping the assets via the compass filter, it's referencing to them in the css files like this :

```
/* Arrow */
/* line 50, icons/arrow/*.png */
.arrow-sprite, .arrow-breadcrumb, .arrow-min_down {
  background: url('img/images/icons/arrow-s8a519b0bc8.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The only problem is that the sprite is contained under `web/img/icons` and not `/img/images/icons`.

I really don't know why the "images" in the path is added automatically.

Thanks for any help.